# Terraform Upgrade to 0.14.0/azurerm to 2.65.0 Causing an Issue regarding SSL Cert in Application Gateway Configuration

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

After upgrading terraform to 0.14.0 and azurerm to 2.65.0 I got three errors regarding ssl certificate configuration in the application gateway section.

---

Error: expected "ssl_certificate.0.key_vault_secret_id" to not be an empty string, got

```
on ~/modules/someservice/gateways.tf line 120, in resource "azurerm_application_gateway" "network":
102:   ssl_certificate {
```

Error: Computed attributes cannot be set

```
on ~/modules/someservice/gateways.tf line 120, in resource "azurerm_application_gateway" "network":
120:   ssl_certificate {
```

Computed attributes cannot be set, but a value was set for
"ssl_certificate.0.id".

Error: Computed attributes cannot be set

```
on ~/modules/someservice/gateways.tf line 120, in resource "azurerm_application_gateway" "network":
120:   ssl_certificate {
```

Computed attributes cannot be set, but a value was set for
"ssl_certificate.0.public_cert_data".

---

But key_vault_secret_id configuratiom is not existing in my code:

```sh
ssl_certificate {
    name     = local.certificate_name
    data     = filebase64("./ssl-cert/appgwcert.pfx")
    password = "SecretPwd"
  }
```

Snippet of the application gateway:

```sh
terraform {
  required_version = "= 0.14.0"
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "2.65.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}


# #################################################################
 
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "pub-ip" {
  name                = "appgw-pubIP"
  resource_group_name = local.resour_group_name
  location            = local.resour_group_location
  allocation_method   = "Dynamic"
}


resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet-01" {
  name                 = "seubnet-app-gateway"
  resource_group_name  = local.resour_group_name
  virtual_network_name = "vnet-app-gateway"
  address_prefixes     = ["10.21.0.0/24"]
}

#&nbsp;since these variables are re-used - a locals block makes this more maintainable
locals {
  resour_group_name              = "app-gateway-test-01"
  resour_group_location          = "westus2"
  backend_address_pool_name      = "backend-pool-test-01"
  frontend_port_name             = "port_443"
  frontend_ip_configuration_name = "appGwPublicFrontendIp"
  http_setting_name              = "http-settings-test-01"
  listener_name                  = "https-listener-01"
  request_routing_rule_name      = "routrul-test-01"
  certificate_name               = "appgw-cert-test-01"
}

resource "azurerm_application_gateway" "network" {
  name                = "app-gateway-test-01"
  resource_group_name = local.resour_group_name
  location            = local.resour_group_location

  sku {
    name     = "Standard_V2"
    tier     = "Standard"
    capacity = 2
  }

  gateway_ip_configuration {
    name      = "appGatewayIpConfig"
    subnet_id = azurerm_subnet.subnet-01.id
  }

  frontend_port {
    name = local.frontend_port_name
    port = 443
  }

  frontend_ip_configuration {
    name                 = local.frontend_ip_configuration_name
    public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.pub-ip.id
  }

  backend_address_pool {
    name = local.backend_address_pool_name
  }

  backend_http_settings {
    name                  = local.http_setting_name
    cookie_based_affinity = "Disabled"
    port                  = 80
    protocol              = "Http"
    request_timeout       = 20
  }

  http_listener {
    name                           = local.listener_name
    frontend_ip_configuration_name = local.frontend_ip_configuration_name
    frontend_port_name             = local.frontend_port_name
    protocol                       = "Https"
    ssl_certificate_name           = local.certificate_name
  }

  ssl_certificate {
    name     = local.certificate_name
    # reference the dummy certificate
    data     = filebase64("./ssl-cert/appgwcert.pfx")
    # this is only a dummy and not the actual certificate to be used thus no harm in storing the password
    password = "SecretPwd"
  }

  request_routing_rule {
    name                       = local.request_routing_rule_name
    rule_type                  = "Basic"
    http_listener_name         = local.listener_name
    backend_address_pool_name  = local.backend_address_pool_name
    backend_http_settings_name = local.http_setting_name
  }

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [ssl_certificate, http_listener] 
    }
}
```

I have no idea how to fix it?

Comment: Hello @techpass, can you please share the application gateway block of the code you are using?

Comment: Also can you please try using latest azurerm version as well?

Comment: @AnsumanBal-MT I tried other vesrions as well as azure rm provider. It doesen't solve the issue. I will post a little more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few problems in your code, I have fixed those and tested on my environment.

1. The Public IP should have `Sku = Standard` and `allocation_method = static`.
2. The **Sku name** in application Gateway is `standard_v2` but the
   **tier** is `Standard` , it should be the same i.e. `standard_v2` .
3. I have used terraform version `1.0.5` instead of using terraform
   version `0.14.0`.

**So, after the changes the code is as below:**

```
terraform {
  required_version = "1.0.5"
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "2.65.0"
    }
  }
}
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}
# #################################################################
 
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "pub-ip" {
  name                = "appgw-pubIP"
  resource_group_name = local.resour_group_name
  location            = local.resour_group_location
  allocation_method   = "Static"
  sku = "standard"
}


resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet-01" {
  name                 = "seubnet-app-gateway"
  resource_group_name  = local.resour_group_name
  virtual_network_name = "ansuman-vnet"
  address_prefixes     = ["172.31.10.0/24"]
}

#&nbsp;since these variables are re-used - a locals block makes this more maintainable
locals {
  resour_group_name              = "myresourcegroup"
  resour_group_location          = "westus2"
  backend_address_pool_name      = "backend-pool-test-01"
  frontend_port_name             = "port_443"
  frontend_ip_configuration_name = "appGwPublicFrontendIp"
  http_setting_name              = "http-settings-test-01"
  listener_name                  = "https-listener-01"
  request_routing_rule_name      = "routrul-test-01"
  certificate_name               = "appgw-cert-test-01"
}

resource "azurerm_application_gateway" "network" {
  name                = "app-gateway-test-01"
  resource_group_name = local.resour_group_name
  location            = local.resour_group_location

  sku {
    name     = "Standard_v2"
    tier     = "Standard_v2"
    capacity = 2
  }

  gateway_ip_configuration {
    name      = "appGatewayIpConfig"
    subnet_id = azurerm_subnet.subnet-01.id
  }

  frontend_port {
    name = local.frontend_port_name
    port = 443
  }

  frontend_ip_configuration {
    name                 = local.frontend_ip_configuration_name
    public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.pub-ip.id
  }

  backend_address_pool {
    name = local.backend_address_pool_name
  }

  backend_http_settings {
    name                  = local.http_setting_name
    cookie_based_affinity = "Disabled"
    port                  = 80
    protocol              = "Http"
    request_timeout       = 20
  }

  http_listener {
    name                           = local.listener_name
    frontend_ip_configuration_name = local.frontend_ip_configuration_name
    frontend_port_name             = local.frontend_port_name
    protocol                       = "Https"
    ssl_certificate_name           = local.certificate_name
  }

  ssl_certificate {
    name     = local.certificate_name
    # reference the dummy certificate
    data     = filebase64("C:/powershellpfx.pfx")
    # this is only a dummy and not the actual certificate to be used thus no harm in storing the password
    password = "password@1234"
  }

  request_routing_rule {
    name                       = local.request_routing_rule_name
    rule_type                  = "Basic"
    http_listener_name         = local.listener_name
    backend_address_pool_name  = local.backend_address_pool_name
    backend_http_settings_name = local.http_setting_name
  }

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [ssl_certificate, http_listener] 
    }
}
```

**Outputs:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: First of all many thanks for your support. I solved it using TF v0.14.9 with no changes on the code

Comment: Np.. Glad to be of Help!:)) @techpass